# Is linear independence of vectors transitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If you have vector $v$ and vector $u$ that are linearly independent to each other. And vector $u$ is also linearly independent to vector $w$ and $w$ is not equal to vector $v$, then does that imply vector $v$ and vector $w$ are also linearly independent?

Comment: Incidentally, transitivity doesn't exclude the $w \neq v$ case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  If $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, then $v$ and $cu$ are linearly independent (where $c$ is a scalar constant).  But $u$ and $cu$ are not linearly independent, hence transitivity fails.

Comment: Curiously,  in the case of a vector space over the $2$-member field $\{0,1\},$ linear independence, in the case $w\ne v,$ actually $is$ transitive.................+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I like it.  I'm going to have to add that to my collection of pathological examples.

Answer (score 3):

No.  In the plane, let $\mathbf{u} = \langle 1, 0 \rangle$, $\mathbf{v} = \langle 0, 1 \rangle$, and $\mathbf{w} = \langle 0, 2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

As a general principle, reflexivity is necessary for transitivity, as you can always just compose $u \sim v$ with $v \sim u$, and if the relation was transitive, this would yield $u \sim u$. So if the relation is not reflexive, it can't possible be transitive.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, it is possible to have relations for which there is never any $ v \sim u$, even if $u \sim v$, such as with the relation $<$. In this case though, that's obvious so we're good.

Comment: This is *almost* true, but you also need some $u \sim v$ (plus either symmetry or $v \sim u$).  If the relation is empty, then it is vacuously transitive and irreflexive.  You can also have an asymmetric transitive irreflexive relation such as $<$ on the reals.

Answer (score 1):

For a pair of vectors, linear dependence means that one is a scalar multiple of another. With that in mind, take $w=\lambda u$, $\lambda\ne 0$. It should be pretty obvious that any vector $v$ that’s not a scalar multiple of $u$ isn’t a scalar multiple of $w$, either.